# how to remove white border from sprite image

Tags: html, css

I just begun to learn how to use image sprites in order to optimize my site better. However, there is this white border on the right and bottom side of my image element. I searched for posts on here and google and cannot seem to figure out how to remove the border.

I did read it was caused by using the image element, however, I need to use this element for SEO purposes. By using a div it would cripple my SEO in regard to images (from what I have read anyways). Can anyone help me figure this out? It did this in both Chrome and Firefox. Thank you

[White border on right and bottom of image container][1]

```
    <img class="image-sprite" src="">

    .image-sprite {
        background: url("../images/gallery-sprite.png");
        background-color: #3a3a3a;
        background-position: -17px -10px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width: 360px;
        height: 470px;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you moving the background -17px and -10px? That will leave a white space under the image and to the right of the image.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to put the background URL directly into the `img` tag in HTML?  Like this:

```css
    .image-sprite {
        background-color: #3a3a3a;
        background-position: -17px -10px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width: 360px;
        height: 470px;
    }
    
    body{
      background-color: gray;
    }
```

```html
    <img class="image-sprite" src="https://w3schools.com/html/img_girl.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

I've posted an example below, see can you find any white space on either side? The problem might be the 'image-size' you using and dimensions that you are placing your image with. If your image finishes by the time it reaches the right end or bottom end, `obviously` then and only then you'll see the white space, otherwise there is no issue in using sprites. Either increase your image in size, or decrease its `width` and `height`.

```css
  .image-sprite {
      background: url("https://picsum.photos/200/300");
      background-position: -10 -10px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
  }
```

```html
<img class="image-sprite">
```

Comment: This code still gives a white border. Look what happens when you give the body a background color, it becomes visible: https://jsfiddle.net/5uyagwds/

Comment: @John - add {border: 0} to class.